# Adding bracket for ggpubr statistical test comparisons

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I got the following code from the tutorial for using the functions in ggpubr, but the output diagram doesn't have the brackets (or lines) underneath the statistical test results.

```
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")
p <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
          color = "supp", palette = "jco",
          add = "jitter")
p + stat_compare_means(aes(group = supp))
```

[image]
If I have to use the `aes(group = x))` argument as the comparing groups for the `stat_compare_means()` function, is there any way to get a line beneath the values such as in the diagram below? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hey Jeff - not a full answer but perhaps what you are looking for is simply geom_bracket from the ggpubr - https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/geom_bracket.html

Comment: I've tried using ```geom_bracket()``` but I can't get the arguments right (since the boxplots are grouped, I don't know what to input for the xmin and xmax such that it is recognized in the ggplot object)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")
p <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
               color = "dose", palette = "jco",
               add = "jitter")
my_comparisons <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") )
p + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons)
```

[image]

Comment: Not really, because in your example, the x axis only has 1 group of data so it can be put into the list for comparisons in ```stat_compare_means()```, however in the problem now, each tick on the axis has two groups (so OJ and VC of dose 0.5) which I can't get the line to show for that comparison. I've tried using the ```comparisons``` argument but it can't recognize the groups inside the variable

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `geom_bracket()` and the parameter `bracket.shorten`.

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
data("ToothGrowth")
p <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
               color = "supp", palette = "jco",
               add = "jitter")

p + geom_bracket(aes(label=p.format, xmin=dose, xmax=dose),
                 # this takes some fiddling to look right
                 y.position=max(ToothGrowth$len) * 1.05,
                 # match this to dodge width
                 bracket.shorten=0.4,
                 # get the p-values from the stats
                 data=compare_means(formula=len~supp, group.by="dose", data=ToothGrowth) %>%
                   # necessary to match the axes on the original plot
                   mutate(dose=factor(dose)))
```

This can be combined with @Brian Montgomery's response as well, though the y-positioning requires tweaking.

```r
my_comparisons <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") )
p + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons,
                       label.y=max(ToothGrowth$len) * c(1.1, 1.15, 1.2)) +
  geom_bracket(aes(label=p.format, xmin=dose, xmax=dose),
               y.position=max(ToothGrowth$len) * 1.05,
               bracket.shorten=0.4,
               data=compare_means(formula=len~supp, group.by="dose", data=ToothGrowth) %>%
                 mutate(dose=factor(dose)))
#> Warning in wilcox.test.default(c(4.2, 11.5, 7.3, 5.8, 6.4, 10, 11.2, 11.2, :
#> cannot compute exact p-value with ties
#> Warning in wilcox.test.default(c(4.2, 11.5, 7.3, 5.8, 6.4, 10, 11.2, 11.2, :
#> cannot compute exact p-value with ties
#> Warning in wilcox.test.default(c(16.5, 16.5, 15.2, 17.3, 22.5, 17.3, 13.6, :
#> cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Trying this solution, the compare_means code (formatted the same as in Debello's answer) works perfectly outside of the geom_bracket function but when I run it in the above format, it says it cannot find object that would be the column in the location of supp in that formula. I've verified that the column does exist in the data set, and even substituting another column name I just get an error saying that it cannot use a column that does not exist.