# Adding Bracket for ggpubr statistical test comparisons returns "object not found" error

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to create a multifactor plot with statistics and I used the method as described here: [Adding bracket for ggpubr statistical test comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69946578/adding-bracket-for-ggpubr-statistical-test-comparisons/73117256#73117256). However, doing so causes an error of "object 'supp' not found".

```
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")

ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
head(ToothGrowth)

p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth,
            aes(
            x = dose,
            y = len,
            fill=supp
            )) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.8,lwd=0.7, alpha=0.6, outlier.color="black", outlier.size=1) + 
  geom_point(shape=21, aes(fill=supp), size=1, position=position_dodge(width=0.8))

p

compare_means(formula=len~supp, group.by="dose", data=ToothGrowth) %>%
  mutate(dose=factor(dose))

p + geom_bracket(aes(label=p.format, xmin=dose, xmax=dose),
           y.position=max(ToothGrowth$len) * 1.05,
           bracket.shorten=0.4,
           data=compare_means(formula=len~supp, group.by="dose", data=ToothGrowth) %>%
              mutate(dose=factor(dose)))`
```

### The correct plot is made when I plot p, and the compare_means code gives the correct tibble output, but when I do the p+geom_bracket code I get the following error:
`Error in` geom_bracket()`: ! Problem while computing aesthetics. ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer. Caused by error in` FUN()`:
! object 'supp' not found

Backtrace:
▆

1. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(x)
2. ├─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
3. │ ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
4. │ └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
5. │   └─ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
6. │     ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
7. │     │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
8. │     │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
9. │     │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
10. │     │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
11. │     │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
12. │     └─ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
13. │       └─l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
14. │         └─ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
15. │           └─base::lapply(aesthetics, eval_tidy, data = data, env = env)
16. │             └─rlang (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
17. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
18. └─rlang (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
19. ```
    └─handlers[[1L]](cnd)
    ```
20. ```
      └─cli::cli_abort(...)
    ```
21. ```
        └─rlang::abort(...)
    ```

`
How should I fix this to get my code to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you specified `fill=supp` as a global aesthetic. Hence, it will be applied in each `geom` layer and `ggplot` will look for and requires a column with name `supp` in the data of each `geom`. This is however not the case in the dataframe returned by `compare_means`. Hence you get an error. To fix that make `fill` a local aes for `geom_boxplot`  too as you already have done for `geom_point`:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
data("ToothGrowth")

ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

p <- ggplot(
  ToothGrowth,
  aes(
    x = dose,
    y = len
  )
) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = supp), width = 0.8, lwd = 0.7, alpha = 0.6, outlier.color = "black", outlier.size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = supp), shape = 21, size = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8))

p + geom_bracket(aes(label = p.format, xmin = dose, xmax = dose),
  y.position = max(ToothGrowth$len) * 1.05,
  bracket.shorten = 0.4,
  data = compare_means(formula = len ~ supp, group.by = "dose", data = ToothGrowth) %>%
    mutate(dose = factor(dose))
)
```

[image]